# intel assembly - using r10d increases cycles

Tags: loops, assembly, intel

I have a loop in my Intel Vector assembly code. In the loop, the loop counter is used to read from and write to 4 consecutive memory locations. For example,

```
   vmovdqu [r9 + rdx + 64], y0
   vmovdqu [r9 + rdx + 96], y1
```

where "rdx" is my loop counter. 
During profiling, I notice that using r10d instead of rdx register increases cycles. 
The initialisation to "r10d" takes 1 byte more than that to "rdx". 
What could be the reason for the cycle increase ?

Comment: The addressing expression `[ r9 + r10d + ...]` will _create an error_ - while you _can_ have 32bit address operands in 64bit mode (via address size override prefixes), you _cannot mix & match_ within the same expression. Can you please show the binary opcode you get, for both cases ?

Comment: @FrankH Assuming you meant `r10`, I'm getting `100000f74:   c4 c1 7e 6f 44 11 40    vmovdqu 0x40(%r9,%rdx,1),%ymm0`, `100000f7b:   c4 c1 7e 6f 4c 11 60    vmovdqu 0x60(%r9,%rdx,1),%ymm1`, `100000f82:   c4 81 7e 6f 44 11 40    vmovdqu 0x40(%r9,%r10,1),%ymm0` and `100000f89:   c4 81 7e 6f 4c 11 60    vmovdqu 0x60(%r9,%r10,1),%ymm1`. They are all the same size.

Comment: Solved. This is because registers > r8 take an extra byte.

Comment: You need to show the entire loop.  In isolation changing the register makes no difference, but in context it could have have a huge difference. You should also mention the processor you're using as this can make a big difference as well.

Answer (score -2):

Solved. This is because registers > r8 take an extra byte.

Comment: As Iwillnotexist explained in his comment changing RDX to R10 doesn't change the length of the instruction. An extra byte, the REX prefix, is necessary to use R8 - R15, but since you're already using R9 that extra byte is already present in the instruction. A second extra byte isn't necessary.

Comment: Actually, I should've looked at Iwillnotexist's examples more closely. They're in fact VEX encoded so they require a 3 byte prefix. The VEX prefix can be 2 bytes long but not if any register used in the memory operand address is in the R8 - R15 range. So using a second such register doesn't change the length of the instruction.